# Create a spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot

I need help.
I'm about to do a test where I've to do a project using spring boot. The teacher don't allow us to search information in previous projects.
A while ago I had a lot of problems configurating projects, conection with database and other dumbs things that take a while to solve (I only have 4 hours to do this test).
Do you guys have a simple spring-boot project or ideas where I can access some projects not using git?

**Really sad that I've a complete project that I can use or see.
Sorry for the dramaa

Comment: just google spring-boot skeleton. I bet that quite some medium articles pop up.

Comment: Thank you. I just found this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf